# XCTest UI tests: only find button when mouse swipe

Tags: ios, xctest

Xcode 8.2, IOS10.2

so when I start UITest, and reach a screen, I use:

```
app.tables.element.swipeUp();
```

or

```
app.swipeUp();
```

can't find the element appear on the screen and code stop at:

```
app.buttons["dingdanBtn"].tap();
```

but if I use my mouse scroll/swipe up(click, hold and move up)

the XCTest can find the element?

Anyone think it is a bug or am I doing something wrong?

If I used

```
app.swipeUp()
```

the

```
print(app.buttons.debugDescription);
```

output was:

```
Find: Target Application 0x6080000ad620
  Output: {
    Application 0x60800017e840: {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}, label: '纳豆行'
  }
  ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Button
    Output: {
      Button 0x60800017e180: traits: 8589934593, {{20.0, 31.0}, {20.7, 20.5}}, label: 'da ren list backBtn'
      Button 0x60800017ca40: traits: 8589934593, {{114.5, 1140.8}, {184.9, 33.1}}, label: '我知道了'
      Button 0x60800017ea80: traits: 8589934593, {{44.2, 1140.8}, {122.0, 33.1}}, label: '否'
      Button 0x60800017e9c0: traits: 8589934593, {{247.8, 1140.8}, {122.0, 33.1}}, label: '是'
      Button 0x60800017d1c0: traits: 8589934593, {{114.5, 1140.8}, {184.9, 33.1}}, label: '我知道了'
    }
```

if I didn't use:

```
app.swipeUp()
```

but scroll with my mouse, the output was:

```
Find: Target Application 0x6000000b5900
  Output: {
    Application 0x600000366300: {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}, label: '纳豆行'
  }
  ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Button
    Output: {
      Button 0x600000366840: traits: 8589934593, {{20.0, 31.0}, {20.7, 20.5}}, label: 'da ren list backBtn'
      Button 0x600000368ac0: traits: 8589934593, {{259.4, 504.6}, {66.2, 22.1}}, label: 'updateButton'
      Button 0x600000368b80: traits: 8589934593, {{336.7, 504.6}, {66.2, 22.1}}, label: 'dingdanBtn'
      Button 0x608000366780: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {77.3, 27.6}}, label: 'updateButton'
      Button 0x608000366300: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {77.3, 27.6}}, label: 'updateButton'
      Button 0x608000367980: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {77.3, 27.6}}, label: 'updateButton'
      Button 0x608000365880: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {77.3, 27.6}}, label: 'updateButton'
      Button 0x60800036b4c0: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {77.3, 27.6}}, label: 'updateButton'
      Button 0x60800036a740: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {77.3, 27.6}}, label: 'updateButton'
      Button 0x60800036b1c0: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {77.3, 27.6}}, label: 'updateButton'
      Button 0x60800036c540: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {77.3, 27.6}}, label: 'updateButton'
      Button 0x608000368040: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {77.3, 27.6}}, label: 'updateButton'
      Button 0x60800036c900: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 0.0}, {77.3, 27.6}}, label: 'updateButton'
      Button 0x60800036bd00: traits: 8589934593, {{114.5, 1140.8}, {184.9, 33.1}}, label: '我知道了'
      Button 0x60800036cfc0: traits: 8589934593, {{44.2, 1140.8}, {122.0, 33.1}}, label: '否'
      Button 0x60800036cf00: traits: 8589934593, {{247.8, 1140.8}, {122.0, 33.1}}, label: '是'
      Button 0x60800036c180: traits: 8589934593, {{114.5, 1140.8}, {184.9, 33.1}}, label: '我知道了'
    }
```

where there is a "dingdanBtn" button that I am looking for

Comment: Does your identifier string match what's in the app? Is the button on screen after the test does the swipe?

Comment: @Oletha the identifier string match the on in the app. the button is on the screen after the test swipe up.

Comment: What is the error/failure message?

Comment: @Oletha Assertion Failure: TalentShangHu.swift:105: UI Testing Failure - No matches found for "daren_shangjia_0001_add_new_photo_album" Cell

Comment: That error message doesn't sound like it's related to any of the code you posted. It's looking for a cell, not a button or a table.

Comment: @Oletha I copied the wrong error message, here is the right one:  Assertion Failure: WoDeHaiTao.swift:49: UI Testing Failure - No matches found for "dingdanBtn" Button

Comment: What is the result of `app.buttons.debugDescription`?

Comment: @Oletha I added log information in the original question, please check my edit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the screen end up at the same scroll position when the test does a swipe as when you do it manually?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133997/discussion-between-oletha-and-harrywilson).